# Recovery of memory especially working memory after depression

Tags: memory, depression, working-memory

The impact of depression on memory and working memory has been discussed extensively in the thread below. 
I can't seem to find information about rehabilitation and recovery of memory after depression. 
Has there been any studies looking at memory improvement after depression?

[What effect can depression have on memory?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/15810/what-effect-can-depression-have-on-memory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can people improve their memory by training themselves to recall previously forgotten memories?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/can-people-improve-their-memory-by-training-themselves-to-recall-previously-forg)

Comment: Good link. But depression (Major Depressive Disorder) was not mentioned in that thread though. Keen to explore that specific angle.

Comment: I see your point, but the point that depression is not specifically mentioned is by-the-by. Although depression is not mentioned, PTSD is mentioned in the answer which can involve depression, and the point that false memories can be induced if anyone was to seek rehabilitative memory recall techniques. Therefore therapists would not ethically enter into any therapeutic sessions to try and recall memories. It is considered unethical.

Comment: Sorry Chris. I am not sure how PTSD and recalled memories is the same as depression.

Comment: Recalled memories I guess is long term memory, but I was keen to look at short term memory as well, working memory, something that recalled memories does not address.

Comment: Disagree with the marked duplicate. It does not address this question at all.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I have not seen any evidence or links between recalled memory in any rehabilitation literature. At a push, maybe recalled memory is a marker for general recovery of memory but I can't see any evidence of that. Happy to be corrected of course. But now instead of focusing on the various aspects of memory, long term, working memory etc, I feel this thread has been hijacked by an off-topic assertion without any evidence.